# JFET + Bipolar source follower: with VGS constant, how Vout can be an AC signal?

Tags: jfet, bipolar, source-follower

Id is the sum of IB and IR1 with IB small.  We can approximatively say Id equals IR1.
BJT give an voltage across R1 equals to VBE.

VR1 = VBE which is limiting the current flowing across R1. In consequence Id= IR1= constant.

Ib also constant.

How Vout can be AC signal if Id is constant?

[image]

**Adding water analogy following Finbarr answer about Vout = Vin-Vgs-VR1**
[image]

**Final conclusion**:
[image]

Comment: Vbe is not a constant. Increase Vbe and you increase Ib and, if properly biased, Ie.

Comment: My bad i misunderstanding VBE=0,6V. VBe shloud be equal or greater for BJT ON. I guess so VBE is relative to Id x R1?

Comment: Notice that constant current means an open circuit for AC signal (large resistance for a AC signal). And we can have a voltage across the open circuit. In this circuit, the Vbe will be slightly "modulated" in the "rhythm" of AC voltage. ΔVbe = ΔIb*r_pi = ΔIb * 26mV/Ibq

Comment: G36, i knew the transresistance rtr formula is applicable for VDS. Thanks to you i know i can use it for VBe.  But still something not clear for me. If JBT admit to obtain VGS constant. How can we have ∆Ib with VGS constant?  VGS constant means Id constant means Ib constant?

Comment: Vout = Vin - Vgs - VR1. So if the latter are both constant then Vout must follow Vin.

Comment: Yes there is the way. But how in micro view that's work? I add a water analogy on my first post. The gate pressure when VGS =0, pressure in Gate is equal to pressure in Source, the path is open at it maximun. When the pressure VGS become negative, the size of the path decreases. If VGS constant, the flow of current will remain the same. So VS will stay constant accross R1 relating to time. VS does not follow Vin in what i see...

Comment: And if -Vss is AC signal?

Comment: What makes you think the path from D to S is open at maximum?

Comment: Suppose we have Vgs = -1V and for Vin = 0V we have Vs= +1V and Vout = +1.6V. But for Vin = +1V we have Vs = 2V and Vout = +2.6V. And the additional current (needed for R2) is coming from BJT not from the JFET. Becouse we have Vgs and Id constans.  Of course, this is not strictly true because Vbe will not be constant in the real world.

Comment: Thank you both for support.  G36 your exemple is clear. Vin fluctuates VS fluctuates in same way to keep VGS constant in your exemple VGS=-1V. Agree. How make the link betwin VS from transconductance response ( what you demonstrates juste before) and VS which is linked by the loadline Id= VS/R1?

Comment: Do you have in mind a small-signal analysis? Because for DC we have Id = Ib + IR1 = Ib1 + Vbe/R1

Comment: I guess i haven't all the key.               
 Id=(Ib1+∆Vbe/r_Pi)+Vbe/R1                          with Vs=Vbe, Vs increase, Id should stay constant. It's a miss match...

Comment: I forgot to take in count R2. VR2= [(hfe+1).Ib + Vbe/R1]/R2

Comment: I got it. I put my final conclusion.

Comment: It looks like you have mixed up the DC analysis with the small signal AC.

Comment: Yes, my previous errors were: 1)Thinking Vs wasn't lagging to VG so in this case if Vg increases Vs still remains the same. 2) Don't take in count JFET and R1 like a voltage divider to set VBE. 3) Thinking VBE equal 0.6V. 4) Didn't knowing the relation and the formula of r_Pi with Vbe and Ib. 5)Focusing BJT too much on positive voltage and not Ib.

Comment: Thank you for adding your knowledge.

Comment: It will be more informations to give about Rin ac/ Rin dc/ Rout for calculating the good value of resistors. Nobody notice?